# How to prevent fragment re-creation in material bottom navigation?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

Hello I'm using  [Material Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation). I have 3 fragment A(Home), B and C. When I move from b to c fragment recreated, data also lost and a fresh network call is sending.

I don't want to lose my data and also I don't want to send a fresh network call.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Material Bottom Navigation is just a View, we need more information on how you're actually navigating between the fragments, how are creating them. Then we could give you advice on how to prevent them from being recreated. That is only one half of the problem though, you'll need to also use some component that is independent of the view's lifecycle, to store and fetch data, like a ViewModel, preferably with a Repository as well.

Comment: Repository fetches and stores data. ViewModel handles two-way communication between the View and itself, and also talks to the Repository and other components. It also holds view-related state that survives the view's lifecycle changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MVVM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) design pattern. If you don't know what it is you can check this [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/#0). Also you can watch this YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orH4K6qBzvE). Actually this is just about ViewModel. ViewModel can store your data and it can show you again even when your fragment recreated (ex. when the user turns the phone sideways).

Inside your ViewModel you need one private MutableLiveData and one public LiveData like below

```
private var _data = MutableLiveData<T>()
val data: LiveData<T>
    get() = _data
```

and you need one function for network call.

```
fun getData() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        _data.postValue(Your Data From Network)
    }
}
```

There it is ! Your ViewModel is done. Good work!

Now we can use this inside Fragment.

Inside your fragment (Which one do you want to use) write this code below the class declaration

```
private val yourViewModel: YourViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

activityViewModels() means if you are using same activity for the all fragment it won't be initilize more than one and your data won't destroy. When you change the activity than ViewModel destroy itself.

You need observer inside your fragment. Observer can observe the data and it call when data change. You can write your observer like below

```
private fun setupObserver() {
    yourViewModel.data.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        // This is a lambda function. When data change inside the viewModel data sending here.
        // Your code here
    })
}
```

Okay now you can call your getData() function using yourViewModel.
You can use this code for this call.

```
private fun getDataIfEmpty() {
    yourViewModel.data.value.also { data: T? // This can be null ->
        if (data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            // if data is null or blank than call getData() function
            yourViewModel.getData().also { setupObserver() }
        } else // if data is not null than you can setup your fragment
    }
}
```

use this code inside your onStart() function.

> You must add this dependencies in your build.gradle(Module: app) file

```
// ViewModel
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
```

> also add this compile options in your build.gradle(Module: app) file rigth below release inside buildTypes

```
   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is working when i no need to pass parameter to viewmodel. When i pass parameter to viewmodel it showing an error cannot create instance of class myViewModel. Help me

Comment: You can use ViewModelFactory. If you don't know how to use check this [article](https://link.medium.com/XnrG5jgpEab)